# Angular Highcharts list of charts with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, highcharts

i'm trying to build an kpi's app and i'm using angular js
i want to create a list of charts , each list item shows different values and each list item chart has different type according to my Model.

i'm based on highcharts-ng directive.

i want to inject through highchart directive some attrs like value, title name and chart type
that when i will type the following ng-repeat it will create my list of charts due to attrs

```
     <li ng-repeat="li in list">
       <highchart config="chart" chartTitle="{{li.name}}" kpiValue="{{li.data}}">
       </highchart>
     </li>
```

you can find my code here
http://jsfiddle.net/Cp73s/62/

link to highcharts-ng : 
https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng

Answer (score 3, accepted):

High chart takes its options from `config` attribute. In your case `chart` object.

Since you want different values for different chart. You have to create as may configuration as the number of charts that need to be created.

Here is the fiddle to show the approach

http://jsfiddle.net/cmyworld/cSek7/

Basically I created a controller to manage these complexities and did setup the initial object settings in the `highChartController`. I did it only for title property, but the idea is the same.

Comment: im trying to solve the problem generically, if i can get the config object through the html why it doesnt works with other attributes?
do i have to write different directives for different chart types ?

Comment: If you look at the implementation of the directive, it creates an isolated scope which contain the config object. All you manipulations should happen through this config object only as the directive does not watch for anything else.

Comment: You don't need to write a different directive for each type of chart. You need to create multiple config object (like you created a `chart` object) for each rendered chart.

Comment: thanks, but i'm still confusing, how do i get the data through the Model into every chart instance ?

Comment: @user2212908 see my fiddle, this should do the job.

Comment: I cannot see the charts rendered in both of the js examples

Answer (score 1):

You have to create a list then add to that list each chart configuration. Use ng-repeat in the list of charts:

```
//See: https://github.com/pablojim/highcharts-ng
var myapp = angular.module('myapp', ["highcharts-ng"]);

 myapp.controller('myctrl', function ($scope) {   

//The list who will contain each chart
$scope.chartlist = [];

//Chart 1
$scope.chartConfig = {
    options: {
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [10, 15]
    }],

}

//Chart 2
$scope.chartConfig2 = {
    options: {
        chart: {
            type: 'bar'
        }
    },
    series: [{
        data: [10, 15, 12, 8, 7]
    }],

}

$scope.chartlist.push($scope.chartConfig);
$scope.chartlist.push($scope.chartConfig2);

});
```

then in your html use ng-repeat on the list of charts:

```
<div ng-app="myapp">
<div ng-controller="myctrl">         
    <div ng-repeat="char in chartlist" class="row">
        <highchart id="chart1" config="char" class="span10"></highchart>            
    </div>           
</div>
```

if you want to use dinamic data you can use a foreach to create each chart config, in this example I create a chart foreach object in the array 'a':

```
$scope.chartlist = [];

var a = [[1, 2],[2,4]];

function chardata(){

    for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {

        $scope.chartConfig = {
            options: {
                chart: {
                    type: 'bar'
                }
            },
            series: [{
                data: a[i]
            }],

        }
        $scope.chartlist.push($scope.chartConfig);
     }

}




chardata();
```